# ajax variable mysql search does not work with space

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I got problem with MYSQL selecting when I use ajax variable which cointains space.
e.g.

```
$city = $_POST["from_ajax"];

$query = "SELECT * FROM `rest` WHERE city='".$city."'";
```

problem is when variable cointains "space" e.g.

variable which ajax sends is: "New York";

mysql query doesn't work.

what can couse this problem?

THANK YOU

Comment: run your query in database SQL

Comment: If you convert your approach to use prepared statements (something you should do to mitigate your current SQL injectoin vulnerability), I would imagine your problem would go away.

Answer (score 2):

use mysql TRIM()

```
$city = $_POST["from_ajax"];
$query = "SELECT * FROM `rest` WHERE TRIM(city)=TRIM('$city')";
```

Comment: WOW IT WORKS! :) THANK YOU

Comment: @luke9999 That's weird .. take a look at the data in your base if this works, "TRIM" only remove leading/trailing spaces so this doesn't have to do with spaces in the city name.

Comment: or php trim() .. $city = trim($_POST["from_ajax"]);

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
$city = $_POST["from_ajax"];
$query = "SELECT * FROM `rest` WHERE city LIKE '%$city%';
```